# What is the best way to load a column from a dataset (.net) into a string[]?

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASP.NET/C# 3.0

I have a method which has the following signature:

public static void SendEmail(string sFrom, string sSubject, string sBody, params string[] sAddresses)

I need to loop through a dataset checking the value of column2.  If the value of column2 is True, the string value from column1 should be added to the sAddresses string[].

The only way I know of is to resize the string[] +1 with every iteration.  This doesn't sound very efficient.  Shirley there's a better way.

Thanks!
Kevin

Answer (score 5):

Use a `List<string>` and add the items there. When you're done, call ToArray to get the string array back.

Answer (score 3):

By default I jump to Linq.  It may not be the best, though:

```
string[] addresses = (from row in table.Rows
                      where ((bool)row[2])
                      select (string)row[1]).ToArray()
```